# JS Regex with variables and possible illegal chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I cannot get this regex string to work in Javascript:

```
var input = $("input").val();
var hi = "(?<=[^ ​ ‍])" + input + "(?=[$ ​ ‍])";
var reg = new RegExp(hi);
alert(reg);
```

The last line is not working, but it does work when the regex is valid. I put the variable into a second string for the full regex search before passing that one to the regex object. Why isn't this regex query valid? (In case you are wondering, the chars in the brackets are space, zwsp, nbsp, and zwj.)

Comment: JavaScript does not support lookbehinds. What is the output of `alert(reg)`? What does *the last line is not working* mean? What exactly are you trying to do, why do you need that expression?

Comment: The last line in the posted code above

Comment: I assumed it supported lookaround. I can work around it, but will have to add extra code.

Comment: Oh, I see. Duh. `alert(reg)` does nothing. No alert.

Comment: After a quick test, I can say what it means: The last line is not executed, the `alert` is not shown. Why? The expression is invalid and throws a syntax error: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=[^ ​ ‍]) foo (?=[$ ​ ‍])/: Invalid group`. The console is useful for debugging! If you *remove* the lookbehind the expression is at least valid (as long as `input` is valid).

Comment: thanks for the help. sorry to waste your time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript regular expressions do not support look-behind.

They do however, support look-ahead, so if you really need the functionality you can reverse the input and write the expression "backwards". If you want both look-ahead and look-behind at the same time, this gets a little complicated.

As you haven't revealed what you're actually trying to achieve, you may be able to avoid the zero-width matches and just use normal capture groups.